# why not redirect to another page after form submit

Tags: forms

I do this in my form submit

```
    $form_state['redirect']='checkout/' . $order->order_id;
```

but it not redirect to `checkout` page ( I test with another urls but it not work),
I take screen shot after set `redirect` , 
[image]

also I get $from_state by ref in function `function pre_register_node_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {`  , **what do you think? where is the problem?**

another note is when I am use `drupal_goto` form not saved !!!, it redirect to my page with out anything saved.

Do you suggest me declare another submit function and add it to submit array of my content type and in it set `redirect`?

**Update**

also I test below

```
 if ($form_id == "pre_register_node_form") {
       $form['#submit'][] = 'mysite_submit_redirect';
}

function mysite_submit_redirect(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'home';
   // ym($form_state);

}
```

but not redirected :(

Comment: A later function in the submit handlers list probably sets a new location. Try adjusting their order.

Comment: @AyeshK tnx note, I will  look at it

Comment: @AyeshK I check it ,but there is nothing else
 `#submit (Array, 1 element)

    0 (String, 29 characters ) pre_register_node_form_submit | (Callback) pre_register_node_form_submit();`

Comment: Did you check `$form_state['no_redirect']` value ? If it was explicitly disallowed with a non-empty value, redirection will be skipped regardless of `$form_state['redirect']` value.

Comment: There is not 'no_redirect` in form_state array

Comment: `$form_state['redirect']` will be ignored if `?destination=[dest]` is set in the page querystring.

Comment: @DavidThomas  I try to get `ym(drupal_get_destination());
    ym($_GET['q']);` they return me  the path I have been there  (add content form ) , and there is not redirect path there

Comment: @DavidThomas also I try `$_GET['q']='checkout/' . $order->order_id;`  or `unset($_GET['q']);` but not worked :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's a node form, the problem is the node submit handler sets the redirect already in [`node_form_submit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form_submit/7)

If you want to redirect to checkout after a node form submit, you can do it by adding a submit handler to the `$form['actions']`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter
 */
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'NODE_TYPE_node_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MODULE_NODE_TYPE_submit';
  }
}

/**
 * NODE_TYPE submit handler
 */
function MODULE_NODE_TYPE_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // You don't need order_id as /checkout will route to the correct location for user
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'checkout';
}
```

Note: You could also do it with Rules.

Comment: May be you could use `array_push` to make sure your redirect is the final redirect.

Comment: @Nikhil M `array_push` is the same as `$array[]` in this case. Both append the item to the array. See the note on: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php A benefit of `array_push` is that it's easier to append multiple items if necessary.

Comment: Yes i agree....

Comment: Yes, this is good solution, tnx

Comment: For what its worth, I found that pushing to submit array in HOOK_form_FORMID_alter also worked, for example mymodule_form_mycontenttype_node_form_alter().