# node not saved if I use drupal goto in submit

Tags: forms

I want to know why node not save if I use `drupal_goto` in the end of `form_submit` function , it redirect to my page but the node not saved !!!

```
function mm_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "pre_register_node_form") {
 $form['#submit'][] = 'mm_submit_redirect';
}



function mm_submit_redirect(&$form, &$form_state) {
   drupal_goto('custom_path');
}
```

Comment: For that it would be better if you provide your submit function. How would we guess what is going wrong otherwise ;-)

Comment: @AjitS you can think I only wrote `drupal_goto('myhpath');` in form_submit

Comment: @zhilevan not enough info Provided. When you ask for help tell us what you did already.

Comment: In a custom form? in a `form_alter` of the node form? Without writing `node_save`. Couldn't figure that out on my own.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @NikhilM the question updated

Comment: @zhilevan the answer by Pushpinder Ranais correct i believe. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See internally when you save any node in drupal number of submissions comes to place. And once you will use `drupal_goto`, it will stop the process there, redirect you and will not execute rest of required functions. There is possibility where you are using `drupal_goto` function in your code, other submit handlers might be required in order to things work properly. If you call `drupal_goto` you would stop the execution flow and make it impossible for the other submit handlers to finish their thing. Now there is two way either you use some another approach for redirection or make sure your redirect submit handler (`drupal_goto`) is last.

I would suggest, you should use `$form_state['redirect']` instead of `drupal_goto`. Once I was using this function in my code and due to this automated cron stopped working, so I would recommend you avoid this function until you dont have other option because there is chance other submit handlers could be skipped, if this function not used properly.

**Use** `$_GET['destination']=$redirect_url;` instead of `$form_state['redirect']=$redirect_url;`.

Comment: tnx for your comment, I agree with you, I use drupal goto because I have strange prolem, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114464/why-not-redirect-to-another-page-after-form-submit . I decide to use drupal goto,

Comment: I try , my submit function is the last function in #submit array in form_alter

Comment: please try this solution once:
https://drupal.org/node/580144#comment-3368072
More info: https://drupal.org/node/942458

Comment: My problem is not drupal_goto , my problem is the `redirect` not work, ,and I try to use drupal_goto instead of $form_state['redirect'] but the node would not saved

Comment: Try $_GET['destination']=$redirect_url; instead of $form_state['redirect'].
https://drupal.org/node/1980516#comment-7357314

Comment: can U please update your question with this note,then I mark it as correct answer, maybe useful for another guys that have the same problem in future ?

Comment: Added this code with my answer.